# Boolean Expression Confusion

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

```
A = S•T + V•W + R•S•T
```

(where • is AND and + is OR)

The answer given says that commutative and distributive laws have been used. However, I can’t get to the answer.

I use commutative and distributive to make

```
    A = S•T + R•S•T + V•W
    A = S•T + S•T•R + V•W
    A = (S•T + S•T)•R + V•W
    A = S•T•R + V•W
```

whereas the answer says:

```
    A = S•T + V•W
```

and Wolfram Alpha confirms the answer. I'm just wondering how it's done.

Comment: Your mistake is from line 2 to line 3 where you factor `S•T + S•T•R` to get `(S•T + S•T)•R`.  You should have gotten `(1 + R)•ST`.  See @PaulR's nice answer (+1).

Comment: Just seen another website. So you basically factorise out the S•T to make S•T(R+1). Right?

Comment: Correct.  And then (R + 1) = 1, so that term simplifies to just S•T as @PaulR shows.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply that the `R*S*T` term is redundant, since you already have `S*T` in the expression, so the state of `R` is irrelevant.

More formally:

```
A = S•T + R•S•T + V•W
```

Collect terms:

```
A = (1+R)•S•T + V•W
```

`1+R` = `1`, so drop this to get:

```
A = S•T + V•W
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where do we get the (1+R) from. Why can we turn one of the ST's into a 1?

Comment: Think of it like this, S, T, and R are three terms. If you can find truth through either two or three of those terms then one of the terms is superfluous. It's something like S*T+S*T*R(this or this and that) = S*T*1(because R doesn't matter in this group and you want to keep the operation the same)+S*T*R = S*T*(R+1)(as in R matters or it doesn't) = S*T*1(if R doesn't matter then it can be considered as true) = S*T(there is no reason to logially AND true since it won't change the result)

Answer (score 1):

Let's just look at this bit:

`S•T + R•S•T`

The right side of the OR can be completely ignored because it defines a subset of the left side of the OR.  If `S•T` is true, then `S•T+anything` will be true